# Making JavaScript Date Object From String Using split and map

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript string, I split it into the numbers for the Date object and then convert to numbers using map.  Date isn't liking the format when it is parsed and mapped.

This doesn't work:

```
var timeString = '2016-01-01T17:44:32';
var dateTime = new Date( timeString.split(/T|:|-/).map(Number) );
```

This doesn't work:

```
var timeString = '2016-01-01T17:44:32';
var x = timeString.split(/T|:|-/).map(Number);
var dateTime = new Date( x );
```

But yet this works:

```
var timeString = '2016-01-01T17:44:32';
var x = timeString.split(/T|:|-/).map(Number);
var dateTime = new Date( x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5] );
```

I'm guessing an array passed to a function or constructor isn't flattened out in JavaScript.  Is there something I'm missing or the first example close to working?  The third solution that works is just ugly.

Comment: Why not just `new Date('2016-01-01T17:44:32')`?

Comment: If you are curious about unpacking arrays into function arguments, read up on `Function.prototype.apply`. It won't work with `new` though, so in that case you may have use `Date.UTC` first to get a UNIX timestamp and use that to create the Date object with `new`.

Comment: @TheShellfisheMeme, because I want to be timezone agnostic.  It thinks it's UTC.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript Date constructor accepts one of the following:

- No parameters, returning a Date object with the current date;
- A date string
- Unix Timestamp in Millisseconds (`Date.now()` is a good example)
- A sequence of arguments, in the following format: `year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]`

In your situation, no manipulation of the string is necessary. Just using this block of code below solves the problem:

```
var timeString = '2016-01-01T17:44:32';
var dateTime = new Date( timeString );
console.log(dateTime.getTime()); // 1451670272000
```

Comment: *"In your situation, no manipulation of the string is necessary"* Sadly, while the string will be reliably parsed, different JavaScript engines will parse it in different timezones: Some will parse it as UTC, others will parse it as local time. This is because the ES5 specification got it wrong (it said no tz indicator = UTC, but ISO-8601 -- the standard it's based on -- said no tz indicator = local time). This was partially fixed in ES2015 (to align with ISO-8601) and refined again in ES2106 (date-only is handled different from date-and-time).£

Answer (score 0):

it's simple, to pass any Array elements to a constructor as  arguments  all you have to do is generate a new constructor with your intended array.

try this :

```js
var timeString = '2016-01-01T17:44:32';

   // now generate new Date Constructor loaded with you array arguments
var arrComponents = timeString.split(/T|:|-/).map(Number);
var newDateConstuctor = Date.bind.apply(Date,arrComponents);

var dateTime = new newDateConstuctor();
```