# How to use 'new Date' method with the result of a function?

Tags: javascript, function, date

I would like to transform integer into date, thanks to the `new Date()` method.
So I wrote my function to get a good format date.

```
function getBussinessDays(number_of_working_days, start_date){
  var start_date = start_date.split("/").join(",");
  console.log(start_date)
}

getBussinessDays(2, "28/12/2016"); // => 28,12,2016
```

When I try to run `new Date`on my result I get :

```
new Date(28,12,2016); // => Mon Jul 09 1934 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Until here it works. But when I add directly the function into `new Date`I get this error :

```
new Date(getBussinessDays(2, "28/12/2016")); // => Invalid date
```

Comment: I think it's because you give it a string and not number

Comment: You'll want to reverse the order of those values…

Comment: Do you `return` your `start_date`, or just `console.log()` it?

Comment: The *slightest glance* at the `Date` constructor in the spec or [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) should tell you *exactly* why `new Date(28,12,2016)` isn't working. (There are two reasons, be sure to look for them both.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118461/making-javascript-date-object-from-string-using-split-and-map

Answer (score 0):

please try this ....

```js
var date = "28/12/2016".split("/");
var d = new Date(parseInt(date[2]), parseInt(date[1]) - 1, parseInt(date[0]));
alert(d);
```

Answer (score -1):

Date object requires you to pass month, year and day values in integer format. You are passing an entire string. Below code would work.

```js
function getBussinessDays(number_of_working_days, start_date){
  var start_date = start_date.split("/");
  return start_date
}
function show()
{
var d = getBussinessDays(2, "28/12/2016")
alert(new Date(parseInt(d[0]),parseInt(d[1]),parseInt(d[2])))
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="show()" value="click"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something like that :

```
function getBussinessDays(number_of_working_days, start_date){
  return start_date.split("/");
}
var date = getBussinessDays(2, "28/12/2016");
new Date(date[2],date[1]-1,date[0]);
```